# In Bootstrap if submenu is clicked parent menu should have a background color

Tags: jquery, css

In bootstrap if user is opening sub-menu page by clicking on sub-menu then its parent menu should have black color background , So that it will be visible under which menu that page is coming.Can some one help me how I can do this by using css or jquery?

Comment: Can you show some code??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao This might not need any code.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy, you just need to modify the `.dropdown.open` class. Give this CSS:

```css
.dropdown.open {background-color: #ccc;}
```

Make sure you specifically target one particular dropdown or the set, else this affects all the dropdowns globally.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  .dropdown.open {background-color: #99f;}
</style>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Take this code as an example

Comment: @Allen That's the answer. Will it work for you?

Comment: No  its not working Praveen Kumar , I have four dropdown menu can you please tell me how I can accumplish above thing?

Comment: @Allen First rule post your code!

Comment: Thanks Praveen for your help. By the  way I fixed it myself by using this css                                                                                                                                     .nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:focus, .nav .open > a:hover {
  background-color: #fcb913 !important;
  border-color: #fcb913;
}

Comment: @Allen Doesn't my answer work for you?